# setContentView not recognizing .xml page

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I added a beginning page to the opening of my app where it lasts for 5 seconds but when i did that it put a little "x" next to setContentView(R.layout.splash); and there is an xml file for it so i dont know why it isn't working. The line I bolded is the one I am having trouble with.

```
package com.jslsoftware;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ILearnSignActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
            Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.jslsoftware.MENU");
            startActivity(menuIntent);              
        }           
        finally{
            finish();               
        }
    }        
    };
    logoTimer.start();          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your import it should not be

```
android.R;
```

but

```
import com.jslsoftware.R;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out is there any errors in the resource folders like drawable, string and layout etc. If errors are there android can't create gen folder. and also check out import android.R.

Answer (score 1):

**Build >> Clean Project**

**Restart your Android Studio / Eclipse**

Answer (score 0):

Scott, if you use Eclipse:

Select your project in the file tree, then goto the Project menu up top -> Clean

This often times helps reassemble and relink your R file with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I deleted this:

```
 import android.R;
```

And replaced with

```
 import com.(ur package).R;
```

It worked out.